# Can this JavaScript Defer code be simplified?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have a JavaScript bootstrapper module that I'm trying to keep very clean and simnple:  Currently I have code like:

```
function bootStrapper() {
       xmlRepository.getAll().done(function (result) {
       autoPolicyForm.show();       
   });
}
```

In xmlRepository I am using a deferred object within getAll();

```
function getAll () {
    var d = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/Autopolicy/dataSource.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            d.resolve(xml);
        }
    });

    return d.promise();
}
```

This code is working well but I would really like to simplify the bootstrapper code further to something like:

```
function bootStrapper() {
       var result = xmlRepository.getAll();
       autoPolicyForm.show();       
   });
}
```

Everything I try results in 'result' being undefined due to the async nature of call.

Does anyone know how to modify the code to move the complexity to the xmlRepository so that the above can be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern jQuery [the ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) returns a promise so you can simplify `getAll` to :

```
function getAll () {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/Autopolicy/dataSource.xml",
        dataType: "xml"
    });
}
```

In other words it is now possible to do

```
$.ajax(url).done(function(xml){...});
```

You could also change getAll to

```
   function fetchAll (callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost/Autopolicy/dataSource.xml",
            dataType: "xml"
        }).done(callback);
    }
```

So you'll do

```
   xmlRepository.fetchAll(function (result) {
       autoPolicyForm.show(); 
   });
```

But apart setting async to false, you can't avoid passing a function as the execution is asynchronous. And you should consider that a javascript application is naturally event based  so it's fine for the users of an API to use and pass anonymous functions (callbacks).

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks, I've implemented it all and it works great.  Especially interesting that the $.ajax returns the promise automatically - I never knew that.

Comment: That wasn't the case in old versions. That's probably why you didn't see it.